# Use a single variable/register for storing 2 values (and reading them by bitmask and/or specific CPU instructions for word size)

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, optimization, assembly

I have a code that deals with structures of data.

My function receives a structure, and go on processing it, just like a FireWall would do with a packet: interpreting it's information, may be even modifying it or converting it to another type of packet.
For example, the function sometimes will transform the structure into another type of structure, and then proceed; the rest of the code will again do other actions depending on the TYPE of the structure.
As I said, it's just like a FireWall; it may change the structure contents or even the entire structure type, and will continue executing rules according to the current structure we have.

This way, for each structure, there are two informations about it that I'll be using all the time, and one is relative to the other (will always change together): the structure's TYPE and it's SIZE.

My first approach was dealing with the structures using two variables: Type and Size.
Every time i decide to transform one structure into another type, I changed the both values, and them continued or jumped to the return code.

But my new idea is this:

- A single variable: Type.
- Instead of an enum, each type value is defined this way:

  ```
  #define MYSTRUCTTYPE__SOMETHING   (0x010000U | 200U)
  #define MYSTRUCTTYPE__OTHERTHING  (0x020000U | 310U)
  #define MYSTRUCTTYPE__LOLIMOUT    (0x030000U | 600U)
  #define MYSTRUCTTYPE__OFIDEIAS    (0x040000U | 600U) /* Yes, there are types with the same size; that's why I don't define a type value by it's size */
  #define MYSTRUCTTYPE__COSMOKRAMER (0x050000U | 400U)
  ```

As you can see, the approach is this:
- Each TYPE value has inside of it it's TYPE and it's size;
- The size is in its lowest 16 bits.
- I don't need to access the other part of the value - the "type" is the entire "(somenumber|size)". Only the size will need to be read alone.

This way, I wouldn't need to update the SIZE and TYPE every time I change the structure type.

Just having the Type variable set, I would also have it's size:
 - ((unsigned short)Type)
 - (Type & 0xFFFFU)
 - in assembly, just refer to the "Type" register as the "AL" part

What I want is to be more efficient: I'm assuming the code generated will just use the same register but considering only the lowest 16 bits, every time I refer to the size.
That seems to be fine to a x86 machine.
But the other common archictectures also have equivalent ways of accessing that lowest part of the register, without modifing it?

If NO, the generated code will have the equivalent of:

```
memcpy(Buff, MyStructure, (Type & 0xFFFFU));   
somewhere[(Type & 0xFFFFU)] = 243432;
printf("Hey man! I have %u bytes!\n", ((unsigned int)Type & 0xFFFFU));

...
```

If the machine does not have a instruction to read only the lowest 16 bits of the register, the operation `(Type & 0xFFFFU)` will be inserted everywhere I was using the "Size" variable before, and this way, it will increase code size.

(A) Do you consider this as a good approach/algorithm?

(B) Even if the machine does not have such kind of instruction, and have to do "(Type & 0xFFFFU)" every time, will it still be better than using 2 variables?

NOTE:
- I'm interested in this as a code optimization, I KNOW IT IS A BAD IDEA TO CARE ABOUT THOSE LITTLE DETAILS JUST TO GAIN 0.00000000us OF SPEED. But I'm dealing with this specific program in the level of Linux Kernel, or 3d game engine, or any real-time code one would spend a little more time to make it be better.
- Sorry for my REALLY BAD ENGLISH.
- Sorry if it is confuse, I edited it so many times that I don't know if my explanation makes any sense to you.

Comment: My question is about a really stupid thing. But it's relevant in the sense that I want to be a better programmer, and I want everyone's opinion if my approach will really remove some bytes of stack size used or if it will do that at the expense of increasing the text segment to compute "(Type & 0xFFFFU)" every time instead of just having that information as a second variable/register.

Comment: I would advise you to start by reading the manual page for `memcpy()`; it appears you have swapped the 2nd and 3rd argument.

Comment: A small note: the `al` register holds the 8 least significant bits of the `eax` (or `rax` on x86_64) register. If you want to benefit from this optimization, you should allocate the 8 LSBs to type. However, it looks extremely unlikely that **any** performance considerations should matter here.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve all this with structures:

```
struct header {
    short id;
    short size;
};

struct message {
    struct header header;
    char* payload;
};

static const struct header  SOMETHING = {0x01, 200};
static const struct header OTHERTHING = {0x02, 310};

void transform(struct message* message) {
    if(message->header.id == SOMETHING.id) {
        message->header = OTHERTHING;
    }
}
```

What you are trying to do is essentially implement your own structure. It's not clear write + bitwise operation is faster than two writes. Leave that job to the compiler. It has better knowledge about underlying system than you and is more likely to generate better assembly.

It won't make your code cleaner either. You are bound to make a mistake in one of those bitwise operations.

Comment: There is also the option of using [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) in macros instead of `const struct`. Might be better if one has plans to replace `static` by `extern` in future.

Comment: No, no, no! Sorry, I didn't specified this: those "structures" are not made by me. Actually, I am reverse engineering another application and I cannot put those members in the structures. Those "types" are the names I give them by myself considering what I am discovering what kind of message they are reporting and the attributes they have.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for packing values of specified sizes is to use bit fields. In your example:

```
struct Descriptor {
    unsigned type : 16;
    unsigned size : 16;
};
```

This specifies a size of 16 bits for both struct fields. In this simple case, you could do the same thing with:

```
struct Descriptor {
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t size;
};
```

While this will typically be packed in a 32-bit word on common compilers, I don't believe this is guaranteed. Implementations are allowed to add padding between the fields. The bit field approach does not have this problem.

If you want to be able to access both fields as a single 32-bit value as well, you can combine the bit field definition with a union:

```
union Descriptor {
    struct separate {
        unsigned type : 16;
        unsigned size : 16;
    };
    unsigned combined : 32;
};
```

The bitfield approach also has the advantage that you can use arbitrary sizes. For example, if you wanted to use 3 fields with sizes 10, 10, and 12 bits, you can use a definition like this:

```
struct Descriptor {
    unsigned field1 : 10;
    unsigned field2 : 10;
    unsigned field3 : 12;
};
```

The compiler will most likely translate accesses to these bit fields into bitmask operations. The main advantage is that the code is very readable, and the code generated by the compiler should be highly optimized.

Comment: Bit fields are overkill here, as you clearly have two short fields, and they don't help solving the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you wand to access your data in two ways: 1) just the 16 bits `Size` field and 2) both fields in a single go, as if it was 32 bits data.

To perform such a hack, you need a union construct.

```
// CAUTION: non-portable (mapping of 32 bits over one int/two shorts mandated)
union Descriptor
{
  int AsAWhole;
  struct Split { short Type, Size; };
};
```

Then `D.AsAWhole` handles the 32 bits, while `D.Split.Size` refers to the `Size` only.

The proper working of the trick can be checked on a **little-endian** machine with

```
union Descriptor D;
D.Split.Type= 0x0123;
D.Split.Size= 0x4567;
assert(D.AsAWhole == 0x45670123);
```

You can also play with address typecasts.

But frankly speaking, this is splitting hairs.

Comment: A `short` is not guaranteed to be 16 bits. Also, I don't believe there is a guarantee that two `short` values in a struct will be packed. There could be padding between them.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The programmer has to check that, enforce the relevant compiler flags and document it. For increased safety, an array of two shorts can be used.